# Visual Studio addin for mass breakpoints

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

When I'm starting with some big code I don't know. I find useful to me to search for a constant or function name and then add a breakpoint at all the references so I can begin to understand the code. Is there a VS adding to do that quickly ?

Answer (score 2):

You could add breakpoint on function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346055/how-do-i-put-a-breakpoint-at-every-messagebox-in-my-application).

Comment: Great tip!  Been using VS for over six years and never knew that.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know that, but you can easily find all references by issuing Find All References in the right click menu.