# How to set breakpoints on lines that match a Task List token in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

This is neat: 
[How do I put a breakpoint at every MessageBox in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346055/how-do-i-put-a-breakpoint-at-every-messagebox-in-my-application)

But is there a way to do this type of thing for tokens in the Task List (View menu -> Task List) as well?
For example, I have code like this:

```
int a=0; //RETEST this code
int b=0; //RETEST this code
```

In the above, RETEST is a Task List token; is there a way to set a breakpoint on all lines matching a certain Task List token quickly without having to go to each line where the token was found?

**UPDATE**

Here is the macro (inspired by [How do I add Debug Breakpoints to lines displayed in a "Find Results" window in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73063/how-do-i-add-debug-breakpoints-to-lines-displayed-in-a-find-results-window-in-v/249501#249501)):

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module CustomMacros
    Sub SetBreakpointsUsingTaskList()

        Dim TL As TaskList = DTE.ToolWindows.TaskList
        Dim TLItem As TaskItem

        For i = 1 To TL.TaskItems.Count
            TLItem = TL.TaskItems.Item(i)
            Try
                DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add("", TLItem.FileName, TLItem.Line)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' breakpoints can't be added everywhere
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no such precanned functionality exists in Visual Studio.  It would likely be possible to do with a Macro.

Comment: Thanks! I should have connected the two..found a macro at:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73063/how-do-i-add-debug-breakpoints-to-lines-displayed-in-a-find-results-window-in-v. Now for some hacking. Will post my results.